# File Search - VB6

Tags: file, search, vb6, directory

I need to search for a specified file, eg. "searchme.txt", within the directory "C:/searchfolder/", the folder has multiple directories and files within it - how can I make it search that folder for "searchme.txt" and return results to a list box?

Previously tried this to get the initial files, but returned no results:

```
Private Sub SearchFolder(srcFol As String)

   Dim fld As Folder, tFld As Folder, fil As File

   Set fld = fso.GetFolder(srcFol)
   If fld.Files.Count + fld.SubFolders.Count > 0 Then
      For Each fil In fld.Files
        list1.AddItem fso.BuildPath(fld.Path, fil.Name)
      Next
      For Each tFld In fld.SubFolders
         If tFld.Files.Count + tFld.SubFolders.Count > 0 Then
             SearchFolder tFld.Path
         End If
      DoEvents
      If m_SearchRunning = False Then
           Exit Sub
      End If
      Next
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How about a simple google search http://tinyurl.com/6ymfcw8

Comment: FileSystemObject, however it returned no results when testing it (the file was present within the folder).

Comment: Please post the code you have so far..

Comment: where is `fso` declared, set?

Comment: fso is a Reference: "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `fso`, it doesn't get set automatically by adding a reference

Add this to the first line in the Sub

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
```

To only add the items that match the filename:

```
 For Each fil In fld.Files
    If fil.Name = "searchme.txt" Then
        list1.AddItem fso.BuildPath(fld.Path, fil.Name)
    End If
 Next
```